# AWS DynamoDB What datatypes are supported by @DynamoDBDocument?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

So, I am trying to annotation an attribute of a table as a `@DynamoDBDocument` to store the object in my table. I'm thinking the actual attribute datatype would be a String [S] but, wanted to confirm this & that it shouldn't be a Map [S] or String Set [SS] or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This link to the AWS documentation has a good explanation for DynamoDBDocument usage:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBDocument

Essentially @DynamoDBDocument indicates that a class can be serialised to JSON. The properties on the class will become key value pairs in the JSON.